# Como aumentar a altura de maneira animada?

Tags: jquery

Estou em um projeto e preciso de um objeto na lateral da página que aumente a altura conforme o *scroll*.

O resultado que consegui até agora está "quebrando" muito conforme vou descendo o *scroll*. Como conseguir algo que seja mais animado ou que apresente uma transição mais suave?

HTML:

```
<header>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div id="broca">
    </div>
</div>
<footer>    
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
header, footer{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
}
#content{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:1500px;
    background:blue;
}
#broca{
    width:50px;
    height:0;
    background:#000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $broca = $('#broca');
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > $broca.height()){
            $broca.height( st );
        }
        if( st == 0 ) {

        } else {
            $broca.show();
        }
    }).scroll();
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nzmdsm1/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `.animate`, mas como o scroll faz executar vários animates ao mesmo tempo, ainda assim pode apresentar algumas paradas, a solução que encontrei foi usar o `.clearQueue` parece que ficou mais linear:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $broca = $('#broca');
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > $broca.height()){
            $broca.clearQueue().animate({
                height: st } , 1000);
        }
        if( st == 0 ) {

        } else {
            $broca.show();
        }
    }).scroll();
})
```

(basta ajustar a velocidade conforme desejado, talvez fazer um cálculo conforme o tamanho do st)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/9nzmdsm1/9/)

Comment: Jader, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pude perceber que no seu exemplo ao subir a barra de rolagem o tamanho da `div` não acompanha como acontece ao descer a scrollBar, então adequei, não sei se era isso que desejava, mas imaginei que sim, caso não queira me avise nos comentários.

Apliquei a propriedade `animate()` que cria a mudança `css` com uma transição;

Então qualquer dúvida me avise que farei o possível para lhe ajudar.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/9nzmdsm1/8/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Samir.
Mas na verdade a ideia do projeto, é a barra NÃO subir, e ficar com o tamanho que estava durante a descida.
O que necessito agora, é que ao fazer o aumento de tamanho, está acontecendo um efeito grosseiro. Preciso que seja mais suave, talvez usando um .animate, porem não consegui implementar.

Comment: O exemplo que você viu o JsFiddle, caso não esteja suave o suficiente você pode aumentar ou diminuir os milissegundos.